# Laravel - select only value from whereExists

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have following query in laravel:

```
User::whereIn('id', $ids)
        ->withExists(['read' => function($q) use($post) {
                return $q->where('post_id',  $post->id);
            }]
        )->select(['id', 'user_name', 'read_exists'])->get();
```

And I would like to select only 'user_name' and information if has any 'read_exist'.
But I have error "unknown column read_exist".

So How can I select only this three values, not all user columns?

Thank you.

Comment: is User table has a column named read_exist ?

Comment: There is no column that named.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the select method before withExist

```
User::whereIn('id', $ids)
->select(['id', 'user_name', 'read_exists'])
->withExists(['read' => function($q) use($post) {
        return $q->where('post_id',  $post->id);
    }]
)->get();
```

It's stated in the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-relationships#other-aggregate-functions)